# Store and print characters but the output is not what is expected

Tags: c++

I'm very new to C++. This code is supposed to store and print out every other number and stop when given the symbol `#`, but the output is weird. It outputs something like `0x6fdd90`. Any help would be much appreciated.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s[11];
    int count = 1, wordlength = 0;
    char a;

    cin.get(a);

    while (a != '#'){
        if (wordlength == 10)
            break;
        if (count % 2 != 0){
            s[wordlength] = a;
            wordlength++;
        }
        cin.get(a);
        count++;
    }
    s[wordlength] = '\0';
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `s` is an array of strings, not a single string. `cout<<s` prints the address of that array. It's not clear why you made it an array in the first place, though.

Comment: `string s[11];` should be `char s[11];` instead. Or you can use `string s;` if you replace `s[wordlength] = a;` with either `s += a;` or `s.push_back(a);` and get rid of `s[wordlength] = '\0';`

Answer (score 0):

```
 cout << s;
```

Is printing the address of the 1st element in your array `s`.
You may want to loop through `s` to print all the elements.

```
for (int i =0; i < sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]); i++) {
    cout<< s[i] << "\n";
}
```

It is better to user char array than string array for your purpose.